# Prove that union of intersections of nested balls in $R^k$ is a perfect set

Tags: real-analysis, compactness, cantor-set

Exercise: Let $S_n$ for $n \geq 1$ be a finite union of disjoint closed balls in $R^k$ of radius at most $2^{-n}$ such that $S_{n+1} \subset S_n$ and $S_{n+1}$ has at least 2 balls inside each ball of $S_n$. Prove that C = $\cap_{n \geq 1} S_n$ is a perfect, nowhere dense compact subset of $R^k$.

I've proved compactness and set being nowhere dense, but I fail to see how it is perfect. The hint in the exercise is to use Cantor set construction for aid.

Comment: For each $x\in C$, construct sequence of points of $C$ that converges to $x$, but never $x$ itself. Also, note that title is written as union, and I think it should be intersection.

Comment: @Riemann In Cantor set construction, we know that left- and rightmost points of the intervals will belong to Cantor set, hence we can prove perfection. Here, the intersection of every sequence of nested closed balls will contain only 1 element (if we assume >=2, we will get that if we take any sequence inside a sequence of nested balls, it will be Cauchy thus convergent, and it will converge to more than 1 element, a contradiction?). Moreover, since the radius of each ball in $S_n$ is _at most_ $2^n$, I don't see how any one element from any of the infinite intersections can be a limit point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $x\in C$. Then $x\in S_n$ for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$. For each $n$, let $B_n$ be the closed ball of $S_n$ that contains $x$.

**Claim.** Each $B_n$ contains a point of $C$ other than $x$.

*Proof.* For fixed $n$, let $B$ be a closed ball of $S_{n+1}$ contained in $B_n$, that does not contain $x$(possible since there are at least two balls inside $B_n$).  Then we show that $B$ contains a point of $C$. Inside $B$, we can choose nested closed balls $B'_m$ of $S_m$, for $m\ge n+1$, and there intersection $\cap_{m=n+1}^{\infty}B'_m\subset\cap_{m=n+1}^{\infty}S_m$ is nonempty, and the point is a point of $C$. This is not $x$ since $x\notin B$. $\blacksquare$

Then let $x_n\in B_n\cap C\setminus\{x\}$. Since $x, x_n\in B_n$, $|x_n-x|\le 2\cdot 2^{-n}\to 0$, so $x_n\to x$.

Comment: Ah!! The proof is trivial, but for some reason I didn't arrive at your statement after the proof. Maybe because Cantor set is a bit "unorthodox". Or I was looking at this in an isolated way, looking for a sequence within nested balls. I'm a bit angry at myself. Thanks. Cantor set is cool.